# Last n digits of BigInteger

Tags: c#, biginteger

I'm looking for fast way to get n last digits of number, represented as BigInteger, lets say, m.

Calculating m mod(10^n) (or converting to string) seems too expensive, because the sizes of n are pretty big. Is there faster way ?

Comment: You can't avoid doing a modulus operation

Comment: Well you pretty much ruled out all options ... The "math" way is the `mod` operation. And the "non-math" way is converting to string and use `Substring`

Comment: _"**seems** too expensive"_ - **is it**, though? Why not spin up a benchmark and look at actual numbers?

Comment: @Selvin maybe. But what other options are there?

Comment: "*Premature optimization is the root of all evil*" (Don Knuth) Ie do a benchmark and check if it really is a problem ...

Comment: @Selvin According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.op_modulus?view=net-7.0) there is no `BigInt % (uint|ulong)` operator. Only `BigInt % BigInt`

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods, mods taking roughly 600ms (total time of execution is ~860ms) for hardest case

Comment: @Selvin But if you want to do `m % 10^n` not only `10^n` (ie the divisor) has to fit in the range of an `ulong` but also `m` (the dividend)

Comment: Vitaly: Can you tell us your requirements? What are the boundaries you are dealing with and how fast do you need it to be?

Comment: What about precalculating possible `10^n`? Or storing some kind of cache with steps?

Comment: Also can you please show some examples?

Comment: @Selvin What do you mean by "inventing new math"? Of course in pure math, there are no ranges. But in programming languages there are. And you cannot convert a `BigInteger` that is out of range for a `ulong` to `ulong` ...  So if you want to turn a `BigInt % BigInt` operation into a `long % long` operation, both operands have to fit into the range of `long` or otherwise you will get a `System.OverflowException` ...  Doing something like `ulong ul = (ulong)somebigint` does not magically truncate the `BigInteger`

Comment: @GuruStron, calculating 10^n ins't a problem, they are taking ~ 60ms (~ 800ms total execution)

Comment: Typically the trick to efficiently compute a number modulo M, is to work modulo M the entire time, to avoid having to deal with numbers that are significantly larger than the modulus. Whether that is possible (and how to do it) depends on your specific calculation, so please elaborate on that

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods, size of biggest number i'm dealing with ~18 000 bits and number of last digits i need is comparable in size with that

Comment: If it's really about a single modular reduction by a constant (or a predictable number anyway, that you can prepare for), you could implement Barrett reduction (which is actually in .NET, namely `BigIntegerCalculator.FastReducer`, but there's no direct access to it). Whether that actually makes sense, or something else makes more sense, again depends on details that you haven't really given yet.

Comment: Please share some sample numbers and how you measure the execution time.

Comment: @GuruStron, i'm using VS Diagnostic tool. Numbers are 1, 5, 6, 76, 376, 625, 9376, ... Their squares are ending with same digits as they are. Algorithm finds them with recursive formula that using square of previous number by certain modulus of power of ten, but that does not matter. Numbers i'm looking for (first 5000 of them) grow in size very quick, roughly 1 numbers per power of 10

Answer (score 3):

Can you use `BigInteger.DivRem()` or `BigInteger.Remainder()`?

For example, to get the last 4 digits, "DivRem" by 10000:

```
BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger(123456789);
BigInteger b2 = new BigInteger(10000);

BigInteger.DivRem(b1, b2, out var b3);

Console.WriteLine(b3); // Prints "6789"
```

Or to get the last 20 digits of a much bigger number:

```
BigInteger b1 = BigInteger.Parse("1234567890123456789012345678901234567890");
BigInteger b2 = BigInteger.Pow(10, 20);

var b3 = BigInteger.Remainder(b1, b2);

Console.WriteLine(b3); // Prints "12345678901234567890"
```

Not sure if this is any faster than using `.ModPow()` though...

---

Addendum: I did try a benchmark:

```
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class Benchmarks
{
    [Benchmark]
    public void DivRem()
    {
        BigInteger.DivRem(b1, b2, out _);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Remainder()
    {
        BigInteger.Remainder(b1, b2);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void ModPow()
    {
        BigInteger.ModPow(b1, 1, b2);
    }

    static readonly BigInteger b1 = BigInteger.Parse("12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890");
    static readonly BigInteger b2 = BigInteger.Pow(10, 100);
}
```

With these results:

```
|    Method |      Mean |    Error |   StdDev |   Gen0 | Allocated |
|---------- |----------:|---------:|---------:|-------:|----------:|
|    DivRem |  96.11 ns | 0.968 ns | 0.905 ns | 0.0076 |     120 B |
| Remainder |  86.89 ns | 0.476 ns | 0.445 ns | 0.0045 |      72 B |
|    ModPow | 167.48 ns | 0.726 ns | 0.679 ns | 0.0045 |      72 B |
```

So it appears that `DivRem()` and `Remainder()` is almost twice as fast, at least for the numbers in the benchmark. Of course, you should try it with the sort of numbers you're actually using because the results may differ!